# sending data to clients from a server in vb

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

Actually I have created a chat application is it possible to send data to particular client only?

Comment: I think there is more info need here.

Comment: I should've put my response in a comment - but yes more info is needed.

Comment: Which version of BASIC are you using? VB.NET, VB, and VBScript are all very different in how you write code.

Comment: I'm removing the SQL Server tag as it doesn't seem obviously related to this. Provide more information if it is.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, we don't know how you implemented the chat application but there's no reason you can't send to a single client.  In fact that's probably what you're doing already, just to every client (in a loop or something).